# Automatic schema generation of mongoDB with the use of Hibernate property

Tags: mongodb, hibernate, auto-generate, database

In hibernate,There is property **hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto** for Relational Database.

```
The hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto option turns on automatic generation of database 
schemas directly into the database.
```

In Relational Database we can use this property.

Is there any property in hibernate for MongoDB  through which we can directly generate MongoDB schemas into Mongo server?

Comment: MongoDB uses [dynamic schemas](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/) which can vary at the document level, so I don't understand what you are trying to achieve with this property. As at MongoDB 2.6 there is no requirement (or server-side validation) for collection schemas.